# Angular 8 - FATAL ERROR while making Universal SSR build - Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: angular, webpack

I've been working on my Angular 8 Universal project for a month. Everything was OK with making SSR builds but a couple of days ago I got stuck with this strange behavior of Webpack or Angular framework, I don't know.

I get the error :

65% building 464/465 modules 1 active p:\web\nodejs projects\ng-express\dist\server.js

---

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

and I noticed that the dist/server.js file is larger than...50MB! It's a bit strange.

[image]

I tried to find any solutions but all of them concern making just a build but not SSR build:

node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot

I need to execute: "npm run build:ssr" command and it's impossible to add "node --max_old_space_size=4096" command before my one.

To be honest, why I receive this error at all? How to sort it out?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved, at least for me, with the latest LTS node version. You can try to update to Node.js v12.13.

If you do not want that, then you should know that webpack + angular + node is known for causing this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618). You can however look at your `package.json`

```
"build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run angular.io-example:server",
"webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
```

if this is in your package.json, you should add extra entries:

```
"ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
"build:ssr:high-mem": "npm run ng-high-memory -- build --prod && npm run ng-high-memory -- run angular.io-example:server && npm run webpack:server"
```

You can then run the build:

```
npm run build:ssr:high-mem
```

This is a bit untested though, so I do advise you to just update your Node version to resolve it

Comment: Many thanks...but not helping. I tried both Node.js v12.13 and then adding the lines  above to my package.json and unfortunately the result is the same - FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. Also it needs to remove "ng" from the script as it gives the error - "The specified command ("ng") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".

Comment: ah yes, `ng` is already in the `ng-high-memory`, I've updated the command. Can you post your package.json?

Comment: Did you mean these lines?     "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
    "build:ssr:high-mem": "npm run ng-high-memory -- build --prod && npm run ng-high-memory -- run angular-starter:server:production && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors".

Comment: @AngryBeaver right, but you should check what you have inside your `package.json` to replace from the command i made with whatever you have written in there

Comment: Yes, this is that I exactly have in my package.json. See the screenshot: http://www.mysite4u.net/tmp/package-json.jpeg . Also I already  told you that unfortunately I got the same result.

Comment: @AngryBeaver strange, you can try to go to 16000, but it's weird that you even need it on a month old project. Feels like there is something else wrong. Did you update to the latest cli?

Comment: @ PierreDuc Thanks for helping! Well, it is ended up with the following: I've  switched to node.js v 12.13 then updated angular/cli then updated webpack and webpack/cli then copied server.ts and webpack.server.config.js from the latest Angular Universal app example. Now it works as it should do with no "node --max_old_space_size=8000"

Comment: @AngryBeaver great to hear. Perhaps they had some bug causing a memory leak in the universal compilation process :)