# While Angular Universal Development Build - FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, angular-universal

While building the angular project for the local environment I have encountered with the following error.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4311:0x3793a00]   132422 ms: Scavenge 1356.8 (1423.3) -> 1356.3 (1423.3) MB, 5.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.108, current mu = 0.049) allocation failure 
[4311:0x3793a00]   132431 ms: Scavenge 1356.8 (1423.3) -> 1356.4 (1423.8) MB, 5.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.108, current mu = 0.049) allocation failure 
[4311:0x3793a00]   132441 ms: Scavenge 1357.2 (1423.8) -> 1356.8 (1424.8) MB, 5.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.108, current mu = 0.049) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x30110765be1d]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x3011076134b0]
Security context: 0x2d973541e6e9 <JSObject>
    2: new SourceNode [0x29fc40a3ea59] [/home/abd/Desktop/xyz/universal_b2c/rg-ui-angular-6/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~35] [pc=0x30110967eb3d](this=0x31d4ced2fa49 <SourceNode map = 0x3797cd0557c1>,aLine=20,aColumn=128,aSource=0x0627aeab1bb9 <String[137]:

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Does this resolve your issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851887/angular-8-fatal-error-while-making-universal-ssr-build-ineffective-mark-comp

Comment: Yes, after adding this `node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng` solve my problem but can you explain what is the main cause

Comment: The main cause is that angular build optimisations get more and more performant, but also more and more greedy for memory/cpu

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing allocated memory size.

Instead of building with `ng build`, you can use `node --max_old_space_size=6144 node_modules/\@angular/cli/bin/ng build`

6144 is the amount of MBs you want to use.

By default, Node.js (up to 11.x ) uses a maximum heap size of 700MB and 1400MB on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms, respectively.

Comment: How much min memory does it require?
I am using the node version 10.13 and angular 10

Comment: By default, Node.js (up to 11.x ) uses a maximum heap size of 700MB and 1400MB on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms, respectively.